# No unchecking for checkboxes whose ids are in the list

Tags: jquery

On my page, i need to prevent checkboxes whose ids are in the list (oh sorry, i've meant 'array' %) from being unchecked. I.e.

```
for id in ["id1", "id2", "id667"]:
    # no unchecking for this id's checkbox, please!
```

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648). Also, SO is not a code wrting service.

Comment: i could paste the code of my attempts, but what for, it ain't working either way. The last time i used jQuery was 100500 million years ago

Comment: This isn't a free code writing service. If you don't know jQuery, pick up a tutorial or read the documentation.

Comment: I hope you do! If I ever ask for someone to write code for me without putting any personal effort into it, someone has hijacked my account and I need a reminder to change the passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
for (let id of ["id1", "id2", "id667"]) {
  $('#' + id).prop('disabled', true);
}
```

We are just disabling the given checkboxes here to prevent from being clicked or changed again.

> Note: **for...in** should not be used to iterate over an `Array` where the index order is important.